# Map Is Zooming (Zoom In/Out) Automatically when i changed Latitude and Longitude To View different location (Please Go through the below Description)

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps

I am using Gmap nuget package to load the map in my project. i have loaded the map, after that i want to draw the circle around the selected Lat Long.
i drawn the circles and those circles are in correct distance also (i have verified).
**The issue is : as i am changing latitude and longitude to to view another location map, the map is zooming automatically.
As latitude number is increases the map is zooming in and as latitude number decreases zooming out is taking place.
I am not using any zoom in/out function only changing latitude is acting like this**

Eg : **Bangalore Latitude:13.095170176351234 and longitude : 77.59453327374854**

For above  lat long assume its in Default Zoom.

**Now I am going Switch the lat long to Dhelhi Location to View Dhelhi Map
Latitude : 28.55635085552201 and Longitude : 77.09994706900083**

while loading Dhelhi Map we can see the Map Zoom In taking place**

**absorve Circle Width,Height and Map while loading To Dhelhi location we can see the Zoom In because latitude number is bigger than bangalore Latitude number**

```
 private static double localLatitude = 13.095170176351234;
 private static double localLongitude = 77.59453327374854;    

private void mapView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
    mapView.MapProvider=GMap.NET.MapProviders.OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance;
    mapView.MinZoom = 12;
    mapView.MaxZoom = 17;
    mapView.Zoom = 14;
    mapView.MouseWheelZoomType = MouseWheelZoomType.ViewCenter;
    mapView.CanDragMap = false;
    mapView.DragButton = MouseButton.Left;
    mapView.Position = new PointLatLng(localLatitude, localLongitude);
    mapView.IsHitTestVisible = true;
    mapView.ShowCenter = true;
    CreateCircle(localLatitude, localLongitude, 30, 0.4, 4);
    CreateCircle(localLatitude, localLongitude, 500, 0.4);
    CreateCircle(localLatitude, localLongitude, 1000, 0.4);
    CreateCircle(localLatitude, localLongitude, 1500, 0.4);
    CreateCircle(localLatitude, localLongitude, 2000, 0.4);
    CreateCircle(localLatitude, localLongitude, 2150, 0.4);
}


private void CreateCircle(double rLat, double rLon, double rangeRadius, double opacity, double ColorIndex = 1)
        {

            //double radius = 2150; // in mtr //todo get from erc
            double radius = rangeRadius;
            //int ColorIndex = 1;

            PointLatLng point = new PointLatLng(rLat, rLon);

            //GMapMarker markers = new GMapMarker(point);
            int segments = 1080;

            List<PointLatLng> pointillist = new List<PointLatLng>();

            for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
            {
                pointillist.Add(FindPointAtDistanceFrom(point, i * (Math.PI / 180), radius / 1000));
            }
            var rangeCircles = new GMapPolygon(pointillist)
            {
                Tag = "RangeCircle"
            };
            mapView.RegenerateShape(rangeCircles);
            switch (ColorIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    ((Path)rangeCircles.Shape).Fill = Brushes.LightGray;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ((Path)rangeCircles.Shape).Fill = Brushes.Orange;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ((Path)rangeCircles.Shape).Fill = Brushes.Aqua;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ((Path)rangeCircles.Shape).Fill = Brushes.Red;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("No search zone found!");
                    break;
            }
            ((Path)rangeCircles.Shape).Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            ((Path)rangeCircles.Shape).StrokeThickness = 1;
            ((Path)rangeCircles.Shape).Opacity = opacity;
            mapView.Markers.Add(rangeCircles);      
        }

private static GMap.NET.PointLatLng FindPointAtDistanceFrom(GMap.NET.PointLatLng startPoint, double initialBearingRadians, double distanceKilometres)
{
     const double radiusEarthKilometres = 6371.01;
     var distRatio = distanceKilometres / radiusEarthKilometres;
     var distRatioSine = Math.Sin(distRatio);
     var distRatioCosine = Math.Cos(distRatio);

     var startLatRad = DegreesToRadians(startPoint.Lat);
     var startLonRad = DegreesToRadians(startPoint.Lng);

     var startLatCos = Math.Cos(startLatRad);
     var startLatSin = Math.Sin(startLatRad);

     var endLatRads = Math.Asin((startLatSin * distRatioCosine) + (startLatCos * distRatioSine * Math.Cos(initialBearingRadians)));
     var endLonRads = startLonRad + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(initialBearingRadians) * distRatioSine * startLatCos, distRatioCosine - startLatSin * Math.Sin(endLatRads));

     return new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(RadiansToDegrees(endLatRads), RadiansToDegrees(endLonRads));
}

 private static double DegreesToRadians(double degrees)
{
  const double degToRadFactor = Math.PI / 180;
  return degrees * degToRadFactor;
}
private static double RadiansToDegrees(double radians)
{
  const double radToDegFactor = 180 / Math.PI;
  return radians * radToDegFactor;
```

}

Comment: Please share the lines of code where you define the map object and set its properties. That may give some clues about the map object's behavior.

Comment: still this issue not resolved for me kindly help me to resolve above issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the `mapView.ShowCenter = true;` property that is causing the automatic zoom adjustments. Requiring the center point to always be visible probably causes your map to zoom to try to show both the new marker and the center in the same visible map window.

Comment: HI, i tried  with "mapView.ShowCenter = false" but still that issue not resolved could u please share me the code which u have tried. it will be helpfull for me. actually i am beginner in this field thats why i am getting confuse.

Comment: Kindly anyone respond me still i am facing this issue.

Comment: HI , Please help me to come out from above mentioned issue.